# Фильтр калмана для трекинга объектов

Tags: c++, opencv

делаю фильтр Калмана для трекинга объектов.

```
KalmanFilterPtr KalmanFilter::create(int dp, int mp, int cp, int type) {
    cp = std::max(cp, 0);

    filter = std::make_shared<cv::KalmanFilter>(dp, mp, cp, type);

    filter->transitionMatrix = cv::Mat::eye(dp, dp, type);

    setIdentity(filter->measurementMatrix);
    setIdentity(filter->processNoiseCov, cv::Scalar::all(1e-5));
    setIdentity(filter->measurementNoiseCov, cv::Scalar::all(1e-1));
    setIdentity(filter->errorCovPost, cv::Scalar::all(2));

    return filter;
}

cv::Mat KalmanFilter::predict(const cv::Rect& rect) {

    filter->statePost.at<float>(0) = rect.x;
    filter->statePost.at<float>(1) = rect.y;
    filter->statePost.at<float>(2) = rect.width;
    filter->statePost.at<float>(3) = rect.height;

    cv::Mat prediction = filter->predict();

    return prediction;
}
```

затем ставлю условие на максимальное расстояние между объектами, но при применении фильтра остаются проблемы с пересекающимися объектами, обгоняющими, они индексированны и в итоге меняются местами . как можно эту проблему решить и сделать фильтр более чувствительным?